# Grouping UV islands

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Is there a way to group uv islands so that the Pack Islands tool would pack the groups instead of the islands. The reason for this is I want to have UV islands from one geometry or cloned objects next to each other. The problem is the way Pack Islands tool handles the operation and shuffles the UV layout so I have to manually fix everything every time I pack something.

Note that the geometry is in a single object and I would prefer to not split it into multiple objects. Also worth noting is that none of the UVs are overlapping.

Comment: I'm pretty certain there is no way to tell blender how to do such thing at the moment of 2.78c.  But I hope there are something like this for the 2.8 release.  Keep an eye on it.  I think this is a much needed feature to help organize UVs in a humanly way.  Many times automatic packing algorithms does a good job at utilizing the UV spaces, but fails at organizing the UV islands in a way that's easily workable for artists.

Comment: It's astonishing that despite how good Blender is at everything else UV mapping is still pretty much heavily work in progress.

Comment: No?  Blender already has all the basic tools for efficient UV mapping and it's all working properly.  Giving it an assessment of "Work in progress" is absolutely not fair.  Unless, ofc, you consider advanced automatic packing algorithm to be one of the basic tools.  And working UV across multiple objects can be tedious without proper addons.

Comment: I know it might seem unfair to call them WIP but comparing the UV tools it's bundled with to pretty much any other commercial software available they don't fare very well. They do the job but that's it.

Comment: @Asutekku of course "pretty much any other commercial software" has much more money (and thus developers) than blender... maybe this feature could be requested, though? did you try?

Comment: Maybe as of today your statement is true.  If you are patient enough, blender 2.8 is said to include a lot improvement to the UV tools alongside many other much needed features to compete with other apps.

Comment: I wasn't sure if such feature existed thus making me ask this question. Requesting it seems a great idea though.

@m.ardito: yes, but from what I've read uv mapping in blender has been a "problem" for several years. I hope the 2.8 update addresses some of the problems I have with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on I just found called Magic UV (available from the user preferences window) that can do this. It is a real life-saver. Hopefully people are still googling this old topic like I was and can find this.

*edit: this isn't actually consistently repeating this behavior, but it did work for me at first. trying to figure out why it worked at first and will not now.

Comment: I just installed Magic UV but can't find do this.